# Windows 7: automute application when it's started

Tags: windows-7, volume-mixer

Title says it all: I want an application to be muted automatically whenever I start it. I seem to remember that the volume adjustments for applications would persist between different times of running them, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore, at least on my computer - maybe I need to configure something to turn that persisting on?

EDIT: After trying a couple of programs, it turns out that it's exactly the program that I want to mute permanently for which the persisting doesn't work. It does work for other programs.

Comment: Since you're having issue with just one application, could you specify which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this on my system and the per app volume setting persisted between closing iTunes and opening it. I have not tried with a reboot, maybe this resets the per-app settings?

Comment: I did try different runs of a program without rebooting in between, and it didn't persist the settings. That probably means it's a configuration issue for me.

Comment: Huh, I tried different programs and it doesn't work for exactly the one that I want to mute permanently. Odd.

Comment: Maybe try updating your Sound Card drivers? Or maybe its related to one specific program.